# How to validate inner entities in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application with javax validation. Is there any way to validate inner entities existence, i.e. many-to-one relationship without marking inner class's id @NotNull and additional long field for FK?

```
@Entity
@Table
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "my_inner_entity_id")
    @NotNull
    private MyInnerEntity innerEntity;

    //@Column(name = "my_inner_entity_id") can't use it
    //@NotNull
    //private Long innerEntityId;

    //setters and getters
}

@Entity
@Table
public class MyInnerEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    //@NotNull can't use it
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private Integer value;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "innerEntity")
    private Set<MyEntity> entities = new HashSet<>();

    //setters and getters
}

@PostMapping
public MyEntity save(@RequestBody @Valid MyEntity entity) {
    //save entity
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by writing custom validator:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = InnerIdValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InnerId {
    String message() default "entity with id is required";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

public class InnerIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<InnerId, IdObject> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(IdObject idObject, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return idObject != null && idObject.getId() != null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@Valid` annotation to `innerEntity` property:

```java
@Valid
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
private MyInnerEntity innerEntity;
```

Comment: It's gonna fail if I use the same MVC interface for innerEntity without passing PK.